# How to sort a List<> that contains derived class objects, by derived class method

Tags: c#, sorting, inheritance

I have a double problem here.  I need to sort a List<> that I know contains objects of a derived class to the class that the list was declared to contain originally.  AND, I need to sort by the return value from a method in that derived class, which takes a parameter.  Keep in mind that I already know the List contains objects all of the derived class type.

I've created some sample code here to demonstrate the question since the real code cannot be shared publicly.  Note, I have no control over the base conditions here (i.e. the fact that the List<> collection's declared contents are the parent class and that it contains objects of the derived class, which contains a method that takes an argument and returns the values that I need to sort the collection by).  So, I doubt I'd be able to use any suggestion that requires changes there.  What I think I need is a way to specify (cast?) what is really in the List so I can access the method defined there. But I'm open to other thoughts for sure.  Otherwise I'm left with a traditional bubble sort.  Thanks.

```
public class Component
{
  public int X;
  public int Y;
}

public class ComponentList : List<Component>
{
  // Other members that deal with Components, generically
}


public class Fence : Component
{
  public int Distance(int FromX, int FromY)
  {
    int returnValue = 0;
    // Caluclate distance...
    return returnValue;
  }
}

public class Yard : Component
{
  // Yada yada yada
}

public class MyCode
{
  public List<Component> MyFences;

  public MyCode(List<Component> Fences, int FromX, int FromY)
  {
    // Sort the fences by their distance from specified X,Y
    Fences.Sort((A as Fence, B as Fence) => A.Distance(FromX, FromY).CompareTo(B.Distance(FromX, FromY)));

    // Or
    List<Fence> sortedFences = MyFences.OrderBy(A => A.Distance(FromX, FromY)).ToList();

    // Or ???
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with casting? Or you just don't know syntax of cast - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx )?

Comment: What happens when `Fences` does in fact contain an object which is not a fence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Enumerable.Cast<Fence>` extension method to transform your `IEnumerable<Component>` to `IEnumerable<Fence>`.  Then I'd use your second approach (the OrderBy approach) to sort it, but that's my preference.

```
List<Fence> sortedFences = MyFences.Cast<Fence>().OrderBy(A => A.Distance(FromX, FromY)).ToList();
```

This approach will throw if there is an object in MyFences that can't be cast to Fence.  If you expect that the code should only be passed Fences, this might be what you want.  If, instead, you want to skip over non-Fence members, you can use:

```
List<Fence> sortedFences = MyFences.OfType<Fence>().OrderBy(A => A.Distance(FromX, FromY)).ToList();
```

Comment: This was the casting tip I needed.  THANKS!  I had thought I needed some type of casting but simply didn't know this.  And there it is...a beautiful thing.